# Convertir peticion de Rest Assured en su correspondiente CURL e imprimirlo en consola con JAVA

Tags: java, rest, curl, test, junit

Necesito poder obtener que operacion CURL se hace en cada test de [Rest Assure](http://rest-assured.io/) . Por ejemplo:

```
 given().relaxedHTTPSValidation().
       auth().basic("name", "password").
       param("grant_type","client_credentials").
 when().
       post("https://test_url/oauth/token").
 then().
       statusCode(200);
```

Quiero obtener e imprimir en consola.

```
  curl --user name:passwoed -k -X POST \
  https://test_url/oauth/token \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -d grant_type=client_credentials
```

Comment: ¿Y que has intentado? ¿Piensas usar el enfoque de interceptor?

Comment: @RuslanLópez no entiendo en que me puede ayudar eso.

Comment: Poner lo que hayas intentado a tí en nada, a las almas caritativas para poder responderte y a los que moderamos para evitar que te voten negativo o cierren tu pregunta.

Comment: Lo que no entiendo que me puede ayudar es el enfoque de interceptor. Lo que he intentado? la respuesta es que no encontré ninguna forma y casi podría concluir que no se puede, pero no quería rendirme sin antes acudir a la comunidad. En cuanto a defender mi pregunta, la pregunta es super interesante porque una cosa es que rest assured te pueda indicar que hubo error en el código (200, 404, 500) o en la respuesta pero para que los desarrolladores puedan ver cual fue la operación y sus datos seria fundamental que te lo traduzca a curl para que lo puedan reproducir por ejemplo en Postman.

Comment: Es totalmente posible, yo lo haría usando el patrón interceptor y por lo visto, ellos también https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#interceptors.

Comment: Bien, voy a investigar que son interceptores entonces. Agradezco la ayuda.